# Why doesn't percentage height work with display: table-cell?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to center both horizontally and vertically a div inside an outer div. It works when the outer div has specific width and height set in pixels like

```
#countdownBox {
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

but it fails when the height and width are percentages like

```
#countdownBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Why is this and is there a work around?

**EDIT** Here is the HTML with container CSS:

```
#countdownBoxContainer {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 3;
}

<div id="countdownBoxContainer">
    <div id="countdownBox">
      <div>
        hi there
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Percentage widths and heights (usually) won't work unless the containing element has a set dimension.

Comment: added HTML. The container is the same size of its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that you have width and height of 100% declared I'm going to assume that you're not expecting anyone to have to scroll here. [See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/zEest/6/) where I have a working solution based on those parameters.

Remember that `display: table-cell;` acts exactly like `<td>` elements and they won't render correctly unless they're in a `<table>` (or a container that is `display: table;`).

The other problem is that `<html>` and `<body>` aren't necessarily the height of the screen if the content is very small. `html, body { height: 100%; }` fixes this but it's a bit hacky.

Comment: This works, thank you. However, to keep a position absolute on the elements, I've had to add yet another outer wrapper containing the display: table div. This means I now have 3 layers of divs just to center an element...seems damn clumsy.

Comment: Why do you need the container to be absolutely positioned?

Comment: Because it needs to overlap other divs.

Comment: Well if you're really put off by the extra wrapper you could use negative margins to get the elements to overlap.

Comment: The most elegant solution would be to use flexboxes. Works flawlessy in Chrome and Safari, but for some reason, Firefox is giving me a lot of trouble with those.

Comment: Agreed. Flexboxes would be great but cross-browser support just isn't there yet...